# Error: Argument 'Ctrl' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: angularjs

```
var myapp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myapp .config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'static/lib/templates/login.html',
        controller: 'Ctrl'
      }).

      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/addOrder'
     });
  }]);
```

My HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="Ctrl" >
.....
</body>
```

I am getting an error saying that my controller is not defined.

Comment: Given that you haven't defined any controller, that seems pretty logical. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

Answer (score 1):

Is your Ctr defined in js file? Typically something like...

```
var app = angular.module('myAPP', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute']);

app.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    console.log("a login ctrl....");
});
```

Make sure you are including the Ctrl script in your HTML:

```
<script src="login.controler.js"></script>
```